# Strip single GET query parameter from Nginx access log and keep all the others

Tags: nginx

I have seen similar questions but not specifically this, **i don't want to stop logging urls with a parameter**, i want to log them without it.

example initial url:

`example.com/dir/file.php?important=1&ignore=random&others=yes`

How it needs to be logged as:

```
example.com/dir/file.php?important=1&others=yes
```

Basically i want to **filter out the 'ignore' parameter** while keeping the rest intact, if present.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to create a custom log format, including a custom variable, and not including the `$request` variable. For example:

```
log_format main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$custom_request" '
                 '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                 '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
```

I'm adding the variable `"$custom_request"`, that doesn't exist. So you need to create it first. And you can create it based on the `$request`, using regex to remove what you don't want.

```
set $custom_request $request;
if ($request_uri ~ "([^\?]*)\?(.*)ignore=([^&]*)&?(.*)") {
    set $original_path $1; 
    set $args_before $2; 
    set $unwanted $3; 
    set $args_after $4; 
    set $args ""; 

    set $custom_request "${original_path}?${args_before}${args_after}";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update to Carlos's answer:
Same:

```html
log_format main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$custom_request" '
                 '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                 '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
```

Different:

```html
set $custom_request "";
if ($request_uri ~ "([^\?]*)\?(.*)auth=([^&]*)&?(.*)") {
    set $original_path $1;
    set $before $2;
    set $unwanted $3;
    set $after $4;
    set $custom_request "${request_method} ${original_path}?${before}auth=*****${after} $server_protocol";
}
```

Note that the `set` and `if` directives must be put in the `server` block. I took out the line `set $args "";` because it wiped the `$args` variable clean for no reason and impacted more than the logs.